# emit multiple objects from PushPullStage

Tags: scala, akka, akka-stream

I've playing around with Akka-Streams and I'm trying to make a custom `Flow` by implementing my own `PushPullStage`. I want the `Flow` to accumulate the objects it receives from upstream into a list, and group them according to some function before emitting the groups downstream when upstream completes.

It seems like quite a simple thing to implement but I can't figure out how to do it! There doesn't seem to be a way to emit multiple objects from a `PushPullStage`.

Here is my implementation so far:

```
class Accumulate[A] extends PushPullStage[A, List[A]] {
    private var groups: List[List[A]] = Nil

    private def group(x: A): List[List[A]] = ...

    override def onPush(elem: A, ctx: Context[A]): SyncDirective = {
      groups = group(elem)
      ctx.pull()
    }

    override def onPull(ctx: Context[A]): SyncDirective =
      if (ctx.isFinishing) {
        for(group <- groups)
          ctx.push(group)    // this doesn't work

        ctx.finish()
      } else {
        ctx.pull()
      }

    override def onUpstreamFinish(ctx: Context[A]): TerminationDirective =
      ctx.absorbTermination()
  }
}
```

***EDIT***

I changed the code to account for brackpressure and it's all working now. Basically I just needed to let the downstream `Flow`'s do what they're meant to and keep pulling elements:

```
class Accumulate[A] extends PushPullStage[A, List[A]] {
    private var groups: List[List[A]] = Nil

    private def group(x: A): List[List[A]] = ...

    override def onPush(elem: A, ctx: Context[A]): SyncDirective = {
      groups = group(elem)
      ctx.pull()
    }

    override def onPull(ctx: Context[A]): SyncDirective =
      if (ctx.isFinishing) {
        groups match {
          case Nil => ctx.finish()

          case head :: tail =>
            groups = tail
            ctx.push(head)
        }
      } else {
        ctx.pull()
      }

    override def onUpstreamFinish(ctx: Context[A]): TerminationDirective =
      ctx.absorbTermination()
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't push more than was asked for, since that would violate back pressure.
Also, worth noting is that I wouldn't recommend what you are attempting to do as this will blow up with an OutOfMemoryError for large or unbounded streams.

```
class Accumulate[A] extends PushPullStage[A, List[A]] {
    private var groups: List[List[A]] = Nil

    private def group(x: A): List[List[A]] = ...

    override def onPush(elem: A, ctx: Context[A]): SyncDirective = {
      groups = group(elem)
      ctx.pull()
    }

    override def onPull(ctx: Context[A]): SyncDirective =
      if (ctx.isFinishing) {
        groups match {
          case Nil => ctx.finish()
          case group :: rest =>
            groups = rest
            ctx.push(group)
        }
      } else {
        ctx.pull()
      }

    override def onUpstreamFinish(ctx: Context[A]): TerminationDirective =
      ctx.absorbTermination()
  }
}
```

Comment: Ahh, I didn't think about back-pressure. I changed the code slightly and now it's working as expected (see my edit). Thanks :)